# Python Running under Java ProcessBuilder cannot not find pandas import

Tags: java, python, processbuilder

I am running a python process in Java using ProcessBuilder.  For now it is a simple test program that prints out a before statement than imports pandas as pd and then prints out another statement.  It's finishing with the error

**import pandas as pd
ImportError: No module named pandas**

Pandas is installed.  Java and ProcessBuilder Just can't find them.

```
def main():
    print("hello world before")
    import pandas as pd
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    print("after the dataframe")


main()
```

```
public class runPythonTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    try{
      ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
      list.add("python");
      list.add("/Users/loisgh/PycharmProjects/pythontest/python_test.py");
      ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(list);
      Process p = pb.start();
      BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
      BufferedReader readerError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
      String line = null;
      while ( (line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
      }
      while ( (line = readerError.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
      }

    }catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}
  }

}
```

Can some tell me how to fix this problem and reveal the location of pandas to java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `ProcessBuilder`, it doesn't take your `PATH` environment variable into account, which breaks imports. To fix this, you have to provide the full path to `ProcessBuilder`, so change this:

```
list.add("python");
```

to the full path to where your python executable is located. Try using `which python` to find it if you're on linux, or `where python` if you're on Windows. You should end up with something like:

```
list.add("users/path/2.7/python");
```

Also, if you have multiple versions of Python installed (e.g. 2.7 and 3.7), make sure you're referring to the correct one, or that both have the module installed.

Comment: It turned out I was using the wrong executable.  Once I found the correct one, it worked.  Thanks.

Comment: Happy to hear that. If this answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution, and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.